# How can I verify amazon keys on correctness programmatically?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, credentials, amazon-ses

I'm connecting to Amazon SES via this php-code

```
$ses = new SesClient([
                    'credentials' => [
                        'key' => KEY,
                        'secret' => SECRET_KEY,
                    ],
                    'region' => REGION,
                    'version' => SES_VERSION,
                ]);
```

How can I recognize here, whether constants KEY and SECRET_KEY are valid or invalid (such as wrong, inputed with typos and so on) ?

Is there any method in AWS SDK to verify it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the Python call get_user(). With no arguments, this call will return the user name based on the access key ID. This validates that the credentials are correct. This technique is not bulletproof, but does provide a simple, quick method. You can test this concept with the CLI `aws iam get-user`.

[Python IAM get_user()](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.get_user)